# Update samba server

Tags: updates, samba

I just [read](http://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2012-1182) that there is a big bug on the samba server. I checked the version and mine is 3.4.7. I'm using samba to share some data, how can I update the samba server under Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is tracked on Launchpad. You can subscribe to the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/978458) and watch the progress.

The latest comment as of today:

> **Tyler Hicks (tyhicks) wrote 14 hours ago:**
>
> Thanks, Ryan! We are aware of the issue and we are currently working
>   on an update.

**Update:**

The fix is released, it should be in your repositories:

```
This bug was fixed in the package samba - 2:3.4.7~dfsg-1ubuntu3.9

---------------
samba (2:3.4.7~dfsg-1ubuntu3.9) lucid-security; urgency=low

  * SECURITY UPDATE: Unauthenticated remote code execution via
    RPC calls (LP: #978458)
    - debian/patches/CVE-2012-1182-1.patch: Fix PIDL compiler to generate code
      that uses the same value for array allocation and array length checks.
      Based on upstream patch.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2012-1182-2.patch: Regenerate PIDL generated files with
      the patched PIDL compiler
    - CVE-2012-1182
 -- Tyler Hicks <email address hidden> Thu, 12 Apr 2012 05:28:44 -0500
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Wait for official package
2. Compile new samba Yourself from source
3. Use untrusted sources